# How many times is it safe to reuse deep frying oil?

Tags: oil, deep-frying

How many times is it safe to reuse deep frying oil for things like french fries, falafel, chicken etc.?  Does the food deep fried make a difference in that regard, i.e. is it safer to reuse oil that vegetarian foods were fried in than meats?